# Does <br> tag take some horizontal space?

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why it renders different two lines vertically separated with a br tag from two lines separated vertically making the first line a block level tag.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qzgeassf/

```css
span.block {
  display: block;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <nav class="bottom-nav">
    <span class="border">
      <span>PORTFOLIO</span>
      <br>
      <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i></span>
    </span>
  </nav>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="border">
    <span class="block">PORTFOLIO</span>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

With Chrome dev tools I can't see what's taking that space at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is white space in the non-`block` span. Remove the white space between the inline elements, and the widths are the same.

```css
span.block {
  display: block;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <nav class="bottom-nav"><span class="border"><span>PORTFOLIO</span><br><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i></span></span></nav>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="border">
    <span class="block">PORTFOLIO</span>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </span>
</div>
```